# JS Programa que se repita ao receber um novo item no Array

Tags: javascript, html, array, input, button

Fiz um programa em JS que mostra na página os itens do Array. Na página também há um botão para adicionar um novo item no Array, mas para ele aparecer, o programa precisaria se repetir. Como fazer isso?

```
<p class="nameDisplay"></p>

<input class="nomeInput" type="text">
<button onclick="funAdd()">Enviar</button>
```

```
var nomeList = ["Gabi", "Miranha"]

function funAdd()
{
  var nomeInput = document.querySelector(".nomeInput").value;
}
nomeList.push(funAdd())

document.querySelector(".nameDisplay").innerText = nomeList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa atualizar seu componente sempre que adicionar um novo valor a lista. Também não tem muita lógica você ter uma função que apenas peqgue o elemento do `input` e não faça nada. Veja que no exemplo que coloquei a função `funAdd` pega o valor do input, adiciona na lista e atualiza o componente com a classe `nameDisplay`.

Também recomendo fortemente você selecionar os componentes do `html` utilizando ids e não classes.

```js
var nomeList = ["Gabi", "Miranha"]
document.querySelector(".nameDisplay").innerText = nomeList;

function funAdd()
{
  var nomeInput = document.querySelector(".nomeInput").value;
  nomeList.push(nomeInput)
  document.querySelector(".nameDisplay").innerText = nomeList;
}
```

```html
<p class="nameDisplay"></p>

<input class="nomeInput" type="text">
<button onclick="funAdd()">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Então precisava apenas repetir o comando dentro da função? Até cheguei a pensar nisso mas eu não sabia se isso era uma boa prática ou apenas uma "gambiarra". E obrigado pela dica das ids.

Comment: Não é gambiarra, vc apenas está atualizando o seu front com seu novo estado.

Answer (score -3):

tenta colocar nomeList.push(nomeInput.value)